# CircleCI 4G memory breach - Django migrations

Tags: django, unit-testing, circleci

We are using circleci for our Django/Python project. While the test database is being setup as part of TransactionTestCase, the memory shoots up to ~3g and hence breaching the 4g limit of our circle ci environment. I debugged using ssh and found that some tests run in parallel where the 4g limit is breached and hence circle ci build fails.

Is there a good way to reduce the memory footprint while setting up databases for tests?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do a mprof using memory_profiler. Disabling migrations brought down the memory usage.